# Create a three columns figure with equations

Tags: equations

I was wondering if anyone would know how to make something similar to what is attached in the image.
[image]

I have the following code but what I am looking for is to be able to transform it into something similar to what I showed in the previous figure.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}\small% added
\text{Roberts}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0\\
                    0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix} \\[3ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & 1\\
                    -1 & 0
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\text{Prewitt}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[4ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 1 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -1 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\ 
\text{Sobel}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    -1 & 0 & -1\\
                    -2 & 0 & 2\\
                    -1 & 0 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[4ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 2 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -2 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Should it be a figure (so something floating) containing math or really an equation? Do the separate equations need to be referenced with a, b, c? Please provide some more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `subfigures`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex,
              font={small,sf},
              labelfont=bf,
              singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \small
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\[
\text{Roberts}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0\\
                    0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix} \\[9ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & 1\\
                    -1 & 0
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\]
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\[
\text{Prewitt}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 1 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -1 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\]
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\[
\text{Sobel}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    -1 & 0 & -1\\
                    -2 & 0 & 2\\
                    -1 & 0 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 2 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -2 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\]
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Example}
\label{eq:2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I need :D